# Why isn't the moderator diamond displayed in community wiki posts?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, community-wiki

I found a [recent (deleted) answer by Ry- ♦](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56417742/10221765) (<10k screenshot below).

[image: Why does this happen?]

The moderator diamond is not shown on the answer. Why is this? Is this a bug?

Comment: MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305546

Comment: By design, as confirmed on Uber-Meta.

Comment: Which brings me to another issue -- why we can't vote-to-close as a duplicate questions on this site that are duplicated on the main meta site?  This has been asked here before, but I've never been satisfied with the answers.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Probably better to ask that as a separate question. It's too bad the existing answers aren't on MSE, though. If they were there, then, in order to close your request as a duplicate, they'd have to implement it. :)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels the literal answer is, I believe, because there is no cross-stack dupe functionality. If there was, it would help with not only Meta SO <-> Meta SE closures but also, say, Movies & TV <-> SciFi (there is frequently overlap). Now, to *actually* address the heart of your question of "why there is no cross stack dupe functionality"...dunno.

Comment: Probably because except exceptionnal case, sites are supposed to have differents scopes, so questions shouldn't have the same answers in differents sites as they'll get answered within the scope of the site. So that would be on purpose by design. Also when you want to close for duplicate, the search box wouldn't be able to search on all sites, but it's true that we could be able to link manually still.

Comment: @Walfrat Actually, many sites have some overlap with others: askubuntu, unix, & [su] all overlap in scope; as do [su], [so] and serverfault. I think the real issue is that each site is a separate ecosystem, with mods on one site free to invent rules that differ from other sites. It'd be a big hassle to get everyone to agree on how to treat dups. E.g, what if an [SO] question were closed as a dup of an [SU] question that was later closed as off-topic? It might not be obvious to mods on one site why a question is or isn't on topic on a sister site.

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to be more wide that our sites all related to IT, since you could say they're quite a subsection to IT, they tend to overlap more than others. But even so, if I ask a question on SO or SU and it's not specific enough to be on-topic only on one, I should get different answer within the bounds of the scope of the site. Of course that's the theory, the practice might differ but I don't think we're that far of that on a global scale.

Comment: @jpaugh it should be remembered that what fits the scope and works as an answer on one site might not on another.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels a question can only be a duplicate of meta.SE if the matter at hand has no specifics for the local site. If such a close reason is added, it should clearly state that, in bold letters, both when voting and when closed.

Comment: You can always manually vote to close as a MSE duplicate. There is nothing that prevents that from happening. And to be honest, aside from the minuscule header there isn't much to indicate a duped link in a legitimate use of the duplicate feature (although I do think there *may* be progress on that front somewhere behind the scenes).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as a duplicate of the Meta Stack Exchange post https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305546/diamond-is-not-shown-for-mod-name-under-wiki-posts

Comment: @Walfrat Afaik the stance of the SE is that the scopes of the sites are defined independently and there is zero to little expectation to not have an overlap. I suspect, the SE wants freedom in order for the better growth. I suspect, it might be a reason, why the question migrations are much harder as they could be, although I don't know if any of my these assumptions had been confirmed by an official source.

Comment: @TravisJ great way to handle cross-site dupes like this! I'd say plus one if I were allowed ;)