# Why was this message in the close status hero box?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, closed-questions, custom-close-reasons, close-dialog

[This question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385704/why-isnt-the-moderator-diamond-displayed-in-community-wiki-posts) was answered on the over meta, and was marked as [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

Some users asked in comments if we could close it as a cross site duplicate (which is a whole other discussion), and I suggested that it is possible to at least use a custom close reason here for that.

So, I entered "I'm voting to close this question as a duplicate of the Meta Stack Exchange post [Diamond is not shown for mod name under wiki posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305546/diamond-is-not-shown-for-mod-name-under-wiki-posts)" into the close reason for other, it automatically posted it as a comment on the post, and 4 other users also agreed.

The question was placed on hold as a result. However, the close status box reads:

> - This question does not appear to be about Stack Overflow or the software that powers the Stack Exchange network, within the scope defined in the help center.
>
> If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit the question.

I don't think that is fair to the question asked. It was clearly on topic here, it was just a duplicate of the over meta, which would have been nice to have been indicated from the custom message in the close reason box there.

Why was that the explanation chosen?

Comment: Isn't that the default close message when closed with a custom reason? I don't see why the linked question should be treated differently.

Comment: @Tom - Yeah, that is the default. Why is the default close message used? One was given.

Comment: So don't close questions just because they're on more than one meta! We've never recommended that and there are many questions asked on multiple metas. If there's an answer on the other question, feel free to quote it in an answer here... but there's no reason to close it!

Comment: @Catija - Some discussion is too large to simply "quote", such as the XY problem, the FGITW, many of the legal explanations, etc. Sure, it is possible to cherry pick in *some* situations, but a blanket statement doesn't really fit all of them like that. Especially where a bug is concerned. There is no need for every single exchange to have an answer for a display bug that was pushed out in a shared css file, for example. That makes no sense, and is also unrealistic to expect the CM or dev team to have to respond on each instance of reporting as would be the norm. They are spread thin as it is.

Comment: You don't have to quote everything. :) I'm a big fan of quoting specific sections and interpreting them for the site in question and then saying "there's a more detailed answer to this [link to answer]". It's a big stretch to say that every question will be asked on every meta. Hasn't happened yet and is unlikely to. We could look into a way to do what you want to do (not sure if that's even possible) but, for now, closing the post isn't really very useful, for a variety of reasons, particularly since it's not really closed, it's a dupe.

Comment: @Catija - Okay, so you raised two points. With regards to closure, duplicates are closed, for the same reason of normal closure: that there does not need to be any answers to that specific question. There is a clear need (and use) in the community for custom closure, especially given the time span since close reason were updated. It seems like a simple thing to do.

Comment: @Catija - With regards to "every question", its true, not *every* question has been asked on every meta... however, it doesn't have to be all of them to have a large impact. It doesn't even have to be most (>50%). All it has to be is a significant enough amount of discussion to cause an overload of those whose time is critically important.

Comment: @Catija - For example, there have been very difficult situations which arise and then play out across the exchange (the issue of welcoming prior to Jay Hanlon's blog for example). Having those bruising conversations on a large handful of metas was *rough*, and didn't allow any sort of coalescence of the issue. It also didn't allow the CM team to properly get ahead of the messaging, which led to having to having to retroactively push out a global message on the blog. As I said, it hasn't been "every question", but it has been enough, and it has been significant in circumstances.

Comment: No, duplicates are duplicates. Even the title bar of the question says [duplicate] and not [closed]. That tells someone immediately that the question will have a link to the answer they need. Again, I'm not saying that making cross-site meta dupes is a bad idea. I am saying that trying to make the existing system work for it isn't a good idea. It sends a lot of the wrong signals.

Comment: @Catija - The existing system isn't working very well for this. It already creates the wrong signal by having answers in comments, answers in tags, no answers on the question, and no accepted answer in these situations at all. When there is a situation where the current system isn't working, then users will naturally attempt to remedy it with the tools they have available to them. That this tool doesn't perfectly fit is just evident of the lack of tooling we have available as community members to effectively handle these situations. I am not convinced doing nothing is a viable option here.

Comment: Where did I say do nothing? I specifically said to write an answer quoting from the MSE answer and link to it. That's the best, recommended solution and what I've seen done (and done myself) all over this network whenever questions are posted on per-site metas that are answered in FAQs or other questions on MSE. That's 100% ok to do in the interim.

Comment: @Catija - 5 years is quite an interim, and as noted, I cover the aspect of quoting above. Please review the previous comments, as I would just repeat those points.

Answer (score 10):

If you use a custom close reason, then it will, by default, select the most generic close reason available on the site.

I would imagine that this would be so that users can't populate a more...*aggressive*...close reason into the box.

Ultimately though, this steadies your hand when closing a question like this.  An uber-Meta dupe isn't closeable here anyway, and having a link to the uber-Meta dupe and having the [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) tag should be signal enough for anyone who wants the authoritative answer.

Comment: I understand that the default gets chosen, I just don't see why it is chosen in the case where every user chose the same custom message. If it was aggressive, then it is either violating our code of conduct or it isn't, which is a separate issue.

Comment: @TravisJ: ...because if *every* user chose the same offensive or aggressive close reason...then we'd have that sticking out like a sore thumb until someone was able to take care of it after the damage had already been done.

Comment: @Makoto think you nailed it better than I did... good to see you around again.

Comment: @Makoto - Sorry, but there just isn't enough evidence to support your claim.

Answer (score 5):

> Yeah, that is the default. Why is the default close message used? One was given

It's a free form text entry box, and you've been around long enough to know what people can do with those. I've seen close reasons along the lines of "*beep* off and do your own homework you lazy stupid *beep*"...

Now imagine if that got displayed as the close reason... There is no sane choice other than to default to a proof-read/approved close reason text.

Comment: Is your example really the same though, did 4 other users also choose that as a close reason? I also feel that using the "this could be abused" approach isn't really much of a defense, as you could just as easily take that position with anything (including comments) which end up displayed on the page. We have ways of dealing with abuse, it shouldn't prevent proper feature development.

Comment: @TravisJ comments aren't displayed quite as prominently on a page as a "hero" like banner as you put it... comments can be removed by a single flag or a mod doing a clear up - they're just not "in your face"... if the reason voted on was actually displayed and offensive/whatever, then it'd take 5 users to remove that banner from the post.

Comment: @TravisJ like I've said - you've been around - have you used your 10k tools yet? Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/tools/question-close-stats - how many of those should be shown prominently at the bottom of a post do you think?

Comment: (some of those should have used existing reasons anyway... but the rest - I'd be curious as to what you think (and whether it'd be worth the risk))

Comment: Yup, aware of all of that. I don't see where you would find abuse in the close reason list you mention. Perhaps a few are a little too blunt, but overall, it doesn't seem bad, especially not the top of the list. Also, it takes many users to remove comments, and if someone is seriously using banned words in the close reasons (which, from the example in tools they aren't) that would be a problem in an of itself. As noted, there are tools for that as well and it is absolutely not prominent. I don't see risk there, to be honest.

Comment: The main argument behind changing close reasons was that there is a custom one. If that isn't really supported, then it should be; or, we need to review and update our close reasons.

Comment: @TravisJ https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210314/categories-other-than-off-topic-should-allow-custom-close-reasons?r=SearchResults&s=1|231.9779

Comment: @Catija - I agree, there needs to be progress made in the realm of close reasons.